# Regarding data using in Bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

Don't know if this sort of question belongs to this forum, but I will give it a shot:

I have started using `bokeh` as an alternative to be able to share Python-generated data and plots in between my colleagues (who don't necessarily have Python, or any knowledge of the language for that matter).

Since some of the data I am using *could potentially be proprietary*, I would like to now how the data is actually stored when outputted from Python as a html-file?

Moreover, will anyone *outside* of my organization be able to get a hold of the data that the file is built up on? Meaning, is the person double-clicking on the .html-file, running it through her Chrome/Explorer the only one that can access the data that is generated in the plots etc., or could someone potentailly snoop the data externally?

Using Python code as in:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file
output_file('data.html', title="test data")
```

Thank you, and hope it's not a too a lame/bad question for this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `output_file` and save the HTML file it is all done so locally; I don't believe it is shared to a cloud service (like plotly).
The HTML file will contain the original data used to produce the plots. If that concerns you, you can save snapshots of the plots with the save button on the toolbar.

Comment: So the file itself is static, and no need for, say, an internet connection to be run?

Comment: By default Bokeh loads its own JavaScript runtime library BokehJS via CDN (i.e. over the network) It does not send the data to make the plot anywhere. If you want to have a completely self-contained, static, standalone HTML file (i.e. that would work behind an airgap) then you want to use "inline" resources. A simple way to get those is to set the environment variable `BOKEH_RESOURCES=inline` Otherwise, the full reference is here: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/resources.html